# Elasticsearch корректировка поиска

Tags: php, поиск, search, elasticsearch

Нужна помощь в настройке поисковика elasticsearch. Проблема состоит в том что на данный момент ищет много лишнего. Например, если забить в поиск "приора" то получим как  и сам приору так и кучу результатов типа "приготовления", "прицепы", "привода" и прочее нинужное.
Я использую [php клиент][1] для работы с эластиком
Сейчас в индексе используеются следующие параметры:

```
        $this->client->indices()->create([
        'index' => 'lots',
        'body' => [
            'mappings' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'type' => 'integer',
                    ],
                    'published_at' => [
                        'type' => 'date',
                    ],
                    'name' => [
                        'type' => 'text',
                    ],
                    'lot_info' => [
                        'type' => 'text',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'settings' => [
                'analysis' => [
                    'char_filter' => [
                        'replace' => [
                            'type' => 'mapping',
                            'mappings' => [
                                '&=> and '
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'filter' => [
                        'word_delimiter' => [
                            'type' => 'word_delimiter',
                            'split_on_numerics' => false,
                            'split_on_case_change' => true,
                            'generate_word_parts' => true,
                            'generate_number_parts' => true,
                                'catenate_all' => true,
//                                'preserve_original' => true,
                                'catenate_numbers' => true,
                            ],
                            'trigrams' => [
                                'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                                'min_gram' => 3,
                                'max_gram' => 4,
                            ],
                        ],
                        'analyzer' => [
                            'default' => [
                                'type' => 'custom',
                                'char_filter' => [
                                    'html_strip',
                                    'replace',
                                ],
                                'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                                'filter' => [
                                    'lowercase',
                                    'word_delimiter',
                                    'trigrams',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

Фильтр ngram режет слово по 3-4 буквы получается "при" "рио" "иор" "ора" и тд. Но при таком использование выдается полный бред после первый пары результатов, отсеять их не получается.

Для себя я представляю алгоритм такого плана, нарезать слово не просто по 3 буквы а учитывать нарезу сначала слова, например "приора", "приор", "прио", "при" и выставить приоритет от большего к меньшему. Это не обязательно должны быть так как я написал, просто это мысли. Если кто знает как сделать поиск более "умным" подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

использовать нграммы как основной поиск плохая идея. Лучше какой нибудь match по ключевым словам. Либо попробуйте добавить к поиску по нграмам minimum_should_match = 90%, хотя это вряд ли сильно поможет.